# How to find Npgsql dll for .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, npgsql

I have Solution in vs 2010 with many projects that are build in .net 2.0, but now I want to add a project that will make Npgsqlconnection, the issue is that I don't know how to find Npgsql.dll for .net 2.0.  Any suggestions please. I can't upgrade project to higher .net version.

Comment: Thanks to Npgsql being [open source](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) you can download it, switch the target version to .NET 2.0, fix compile errors, run tests and fix their errors

Comment: The [version 2.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/2.2.7) download on nuget has binaries for net20 and net35 (which uses the 2.0 runtime). Of course it's nearly five years old and may not work against modern versions of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have downloaded the version 2.2.7 and now how do i include it in my project? Thanks a lot, i`m new in this and i know that maybe this may be silly question but i hope you can help .

Answer (score 2):

By having a look at their repository you can see that the latest nuspec-file that contains a reference to .Net Framework 2.0 is tagged with [version 2.2.7](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/v2.2.7/Npgsql/Npgsql.nuspec). So you should be able to use that version from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/2.2.7). However, this is two major versions behind the current version (and the next major version is available as an alpha) so you might have some problems finding relevant API documentation for your version.

Also note that this release is from 2015, so it might not work properly or support all features found in PostgreSQL versions from after that.

Comment: I have downloaded the version 2.2.7 and now how do i include it in my project? Thanks a lot, i`m new in this and i know that maybe this may be silly question but i hope you can help

Comment: Look into how to add a nuget package as a reference to your project. It varies a bit depending on your version av Visual Studio.

Comment: Alternatively if you can't make nuget work you can unzip the nupkg file and take the DLLs from the lib\net20 folder. But I'd recommend using nuget if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i`ll try and let you know.

Comment: I unzip the nupkg file and added Npgsql.dll into my project as Reference and when I run it i got this error :   Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=2.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest version of .NET 2 at least, so that you can then load this assembly? If not, I'd check out the v2.2.7 tag from Karl-Johan's GitHub link and build it yourself then.